# Source Resistance

Tags: amplifier, resistance

I have a module that generate an AC signal for a measurement it makes. Frequency and Amplitude output provides information and we use that. Now I am designing a better amplifier for the module and I am trying to figure out what is the source resistance of this module. (The resistance seen from the amplifier).

Unfortunately, datasheet offers no clues. How can I measure source resistance of this unknown entity in a reliable way?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ieAhBejHe2M

Comment: It's unknown to us too - how about providing some information on the "thing" and maybe a link to its data sheet. Nobody on SE.EE is a mind reader last time I checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a voltage divider made by the source resistance and an additional potentiometer placed by you , measure the output voltage and adjust the potentiometer until the output voltage from voltage divider is half from the original output voltage.